# What would happen if there are two intent filters with CATEGORY_LAUNCHER?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

One category_launcher is under MainActivity and other under some other activity.
1) Is it allowed to have two category_launcher?
PS: I see answers saying that there will be two activities, two entry points etc. 
2) I am curious to know How can two activities been shown at same time? 
3) Are they shown one after other? If yes, in what order?
3) If we click the app icon (in home), the app gets launched. I don't get two entry points concept.

Comment: create a project and implement it.

Comment: I did. The activity that is placed at bottom with launcher gets shown. But I am not sure, if Android resolves all launchers mentioned in the AndroidManifest.xml and the bottom most one gets shown. Or if some other logic is there? Also Not sure if it is ok to do that and if yes under what situation one would need it.

Comment: when you provide two Launcher categroy in different activity tag, two launcher icons will be shown in the Launcher. but what is the issue ? are you only getting one launcher icon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define two activities to be placed in launcher. There will be **two** entry points (from launcher) for you app. You will have both activities in the launcher.

Also note that

> In order to receive implicit intents, you must include the
>   CATEGORY_DEFAULT category in the intent filter. The methods
>   startActivity() and startActivityForResult() treat all intents as if
>   they declared the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category. If you do not declare it
>   in your intent filter, no implicit intents will resolve to your
>   activity.

**Updated**

Ordering depends on the **name of activities**, they will be sorted **alphabetically** in launcher. i.e. from two launcher activities with names `A` and `B`, activity with name starting from `A` will appear first in launcher.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am curious to know How can two activities been shown at same time? Are they shown one after other? If yes, in what order?  If we click the app icon in home, the app gets launched. I don't get two entry points concept.

Comment: By **two entry points** I mean, you will have two activities appearing in the `launcher` and clicking on any of those will **open** your app, in short now you can **start your app (enter into your app)** from two different activities in launcher.

Comment: Thanks. This might be a stupid question, but to not have assumption, "What is a launcher in android?"

Comment: Ok. I understood and I tried adding two launchers and I see two icons on home screen, And if I click one it takes me to one part of the app and other takes me to other part of the app. But my next question is if an app's AndroidManifest.xml has more than two activities and each has of the activity has intent-filter with action=android.intent.action.MAIN but no category mentioned. Then what's it purpose. I read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN - it states its an entry point.

Comment: close this question and ask a new one.

Comment: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523925/what-does-it-mean-when-two-or-more-activities-each-having-intent-filter-with-ac

Answer (score 1):

You will show both activity on Home screen of device!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am curious to know How can two activities been shown at same time? Are they shown one after other? If yes, in what order?

Answer (score 1):

Both the activities will appear in the launcher!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am curious to know How can two activities been shown at same time? Are they shown one after other? If yes, in what order?

Comment: No if they have a label then they will appear with that label alphabetically. Otherwise Activityname (Classname) will be used.