# What does it mean when two or more activities, each having intent-filter with action=android.intent.action.ACTION_MAIN?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-implicit-intent

Doc says https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN  is an entry point.

Example code:

```
 <activity android:name="org.A.A"
            android:theme="@style/NoTitle"
            android:screenOrientation="behind"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="org.A.C"
            android:theme="@style/NoTitle"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="behind">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="org.A.B"
            android:theme="@style/NoTitle"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="behind">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

1) So using android.intent.action.ACTION_MAIN acts as an entry point to the parent component (parent component I mean the activity or receiver or service)?

2) If yes, Entry point from where, as there is no CATEGORY mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android apps are composed of different components. e.g. `Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, and `ContentProvider` and each component can act as an **entry point** of the app.

Let's take **activity** as an example, you have defined an activity in your application with following action

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.yourapp.SOME_ACTION" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

and I start an activity in **my** app with following intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.yourapp.SOME_ACTION"); // same action
startActivity(intent);
```

Now what will happen? System will search for activities with `com.yourapp.SOME_ACTION` action and if it finds one (in current scenario, it will be activity you have created with `com.yourapp.SOME_ACTION` in your app), it will **start your app** (if it is not already started) and will open the activity in your app.

See, now I can **enter** into your app by using `Activity` with `com.yourapp.SOME_ACTION`. Same thing happens in case of other components.

Comment: Thanks for answering. "....and each component can act as an entry point of the app." - Does it mean, "each component can act as an entry point of the app from outside the app"?

Comment: Yes. That's true.

Comment: In your intent-filter example, I noticed that you have used category. But my question 2) and the code I have given has no category but action_MAIN in all activities under single AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: That's because I am using **implicit intent** to open activity and **default category** is required for implicit intents.

Comment: Pleaese go through https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727828/what-is-the-purpose-of-android-intent-category-default

Comment: If you are not adding default category, it mean you are not allowing your activity to be opened by implicit intents.

Comment: Perfect timing. :) I was reading those two links. Ok here is my question. The code that I have put in question is from open source project. I am trying to understand what it does. I understood what is default category, implicit intent and action. 

But I couldn't get what would be the purpose of those 3 activities with ACTION_MAIN intent filter but no category.

Comment: The app will be using these activities **with in** the app. If you need to start an activity you will have to do it by intent. For starting these activities you can use **explicit** intent. like `Intent intent = new Intent(context,org.A.C.class); `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914881/android-implicit-intents-vs-explicit-intents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132581/discussion-between-user3705478-and-mallaudin).

Answer (score 0):

Activity with MAIN action will be entry point of application.If you have one its well and good if more than one then you can have multiple activities through which you can enter into application.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But if you have provided CATEGORY for activity it will create launcher for that entry point.

```
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Suppose two activities is having both MAIN action and CATEGORY as launcher two app icon will be created one will have one activity as entry point second will have another one as entry point.

```
    <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
```